# Exception while copying text from edittext to clipboard via context menus?

Tags: android, copy, textview, contextmenu, clipboard

**Am I doing something wrong when trying to copy TextView text to the clipboard?**

My Code in my Activity Class:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    String selectedItem = item.getTitle().toString().trim();
    try {
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip;
    if (selectedItem.equals("Copy Query")) {
        clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Query",tv1.getText());
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }           
    return true;
}
```

The error:

```
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.content.ClipboardManager
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at com.ewe.radixcalculator.CalculatorActivity.onContextItemSelected(CalculatorActivity.java:68)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2199)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:2744)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:137)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:874)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.content.ClipboardManager in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.ewe.radixcalculator-2.apk]
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-17 03:10:54.056: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
```

Comment: I got this error on an Android 2.2 emulator and on my Android 2.2 device.

Comment: I think ClipboardManager is since API level 11...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11012443/2116185 for the correct way to get a ClipboardManager object on different Android API versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your stacktrace, it is obvious that `ClipboardManager` you are using is not found. A quick look up shows me that there are two `ClipboardManager` in Android.

1. [`ClipboardManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html) (android.text.ClipboardManager) since API 1
2. [`ClipboardManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html) (android.content.ClipboardManager) since API 11

According to your implementation, I can guess that you intend to use latter one which only include in API 11. Thus, your code resulting in error.

Eclipse doesn't show you error because you had imported `android.text.ClipboardManager` in your import section.

To solve the problem, import the correct package and point to relevant API version.

If you want to use `android.text.ClipboardManager` for older versions, I think it should be fine. Here is how I would do it. Hope this helps.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    String selectedItem = item.getTitle().toString().trim();
    try {
    ClipboardManager clipboard = new ClipboardManager();
    if (selectedItem.equals("Copy Query")) {
        clipboard.setText(tv1.getText().toString());
    }           
    return true;
}
```