# Copy the value of the list item when the list item is clicked

Tags: list, copy, clipboard, listitem

I am making an Android application and want to add a feature of click to copy the list item value.
When any list item will be clicked the value of the list item should copy to clipboard.
Can somebody help ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253786/how-to-copy-text-to-clip-board-in-android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238284/how-to-copy-text-programmatically-in-my-android-app

Comment: The list click can be detected using list.onItemClickListener. Copying of the selected text can be implemented using the above two links.