# Copy text to other app via clipboard

Tags: android, copy, copy-paste, clipboarddata

[image]

I want to copy these text and past into other apps like WhatsApp twitter etc to the clipboard by clicking this (copy tag button) how can I do here is my activity

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253786/how-to-copy-text-to-clip-board-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can copy something to clipboard using something like this:

ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("some label", floatingTextButton.getText().toString());
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: .getText().toString()); did not use in android s3