# How to copy a value to clipboard

Tags: android, clipboard, zxing, android-clipboardmanager

I am currently trying to include a copy to clipboard function for my app. My app is a barcode scanner that produces 2 buttons upon the successful scanning of a barcode/QR code. The 2 buttons are "visit" and "ok", i would like to add an extra button called "copy to clipboard" which obtains the value produced by the barcode scanner, and copies it to clipboard on the android device. The android-studio version i am using is 2.3.3

Here is my source code (the part where the buttons are programmed is in the last subroutine) :

```
package com.example.priyanka.qrbarcodescanner;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;


import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private static String myResult;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
    private static int camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(scannerView);
        int currentApiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        if(currentApiVersion >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if(checkPermission())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission already granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermission()
    {
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    private void requestPermission()
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkPermission()) {
                if(scannerView == null) {
                    scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
                    setContentView(scannerView);
                }
                scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
                scannerView.startCamera();
            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CAMERA:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (cameraAccepted){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted, Now you can access camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied, You cannot access and camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA)) {
                                showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                    requestPermissions(new String[]{CAMERA},
                                                            REQUEST_CAMERA);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getText());
        Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
        myResult = result.getText();


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);

            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("Visit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent browserIntent;
                if (myResult.startsWith("http://") || myResult.startsWith("https://"))
                    browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myResult));
                else
                    browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://google.com/search?q=" + myResult));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });
        builder.setMessage(result.getText());
        AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
        alert1.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to look in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253786/how-to-copy-text-to-clip-board-in-android)?

Comment: Hey @Thor, yes i've tried following that thread before but for some reason i find no success... maybe i am putting the code in the wrong place? (and yes i have imported clipboard manager)

Answer (score 5):

The kotlin answer above do not work for me

```
var myClipboard = context!!.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
var myClip: ClipData = ClipData.newPlainText("note_copy", url)
myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java using ClipBoardManager, This works on all versions

```
   private void setClipboard(Context context, String text) {
  if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.setText(text);
  } else {
    android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", text);
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
  }
}
```