# URL not showing in android studio logcat

Tags: android-studio, logcat

When I am trying to log any URL like we have an URL for an API call
I tried

```
            url = "https://google.com"
            Log.e("url",url)
```

This is how a URL is shown

```
E/url: ******************
```

I am using Windows 10 Android Studio:

- Android Studio 4.2.1
- Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7351085, built on May 10, 2021
- Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174 amd64
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by N/A
- Windows 10 10.0
- GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
- Memory: 1280M
- Cores: 8
- Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

Comment: I programmatically copied the URL to the android device clipboard https://stackoverflow.com/a/19253868/12575211

Comment: Copying the url to clipboard! Will that print the API urls to logcat?

Comment: No, you can past it somewhere in phone and do whatever you want. I know, it is not good option if working with many api calls but I didn't get any other solution.

Comment: I am working with a lot of APIs in the same project and I am facing this issue. Have you found any good solution?

Comment: Facing same issue on Android version 11 using Volley LIB.                                             E/appurl: ******************************************************************************                  But on Android os 6.0.1 App Url logged in Log.e("","") function .

Comment: Same happening in Vivo y33s with android 11

Answer (score 0):

if in Logcat URL is not printed then uninstall app and install again it is working (Vivo android 12)

Comment: For me restarting Android studio helped.