# Android Studio Copy Text Problem solve Please?

Tags: kotlin

try { var a = InputText.text.toString()
var c =InputNumber.text.toString()

```
 var copyText = ShowText.setText(a.repeat(c.toInt())).toString()
```

}catch (e: Exception){

```
 Toast.makeText(this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
```

}
})

```
    var CopyButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.CopyButtonId)
    var ShareButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.ShareButtonId)

    CopyButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        val clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("CopyT Tex", "HERE HOW I GOT MY copyText Data")
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)

    })
```

Comment: You might want to briefly explain what problems you faced, does the clipboard failed or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253786/how-to-copy-text-to-clip-board-in-android) for further advice.

FYI:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(label, text);  
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

Use [Clipboard Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html)