# Copying text to clipboad

Tags: android

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final holderView holderView, final int position) {
     holderView.insptext.setText(inspirationItemsList.get(position).getName());
     holderView.copy.setImageResource(inspirationItemsList.get(position).getCopy());
     holderView.share.setImageResource(inspirationItemsList.get(position).getShare());



        holderView.copy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){



                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Copied to clipboard" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: What is your question??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy to clipboard programatically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238284/how-to-copy-text-programmatically-in-my-android-app) is the reference link :

And this is how you implement it :

```
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "Text to copy");
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

And [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html) is the documentation for the ClipboardManager

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22775916)

Comment: I am updating the answer here

Answer (score -1):

In order to copy something in your clipboard, use the code below:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(label, text);
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```