# Does copying to clipboard on Android require special permission?

Tags: java, android, clipboard

I want to make an Android app that displays latitude and longitude and features a button that copies them both to the clipboard.

Does copying to the clipboard require special permission on Android?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238284/how-to-copy-text-programmatically-in-my-android-app

Comment: No you do not need any permission.